# C++ Error for file_size() which belongs to Boost Filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

My IDE is  MS Visual Studio C++ 2013, and I use Boost Library for Filesystem Operations.
I have written this code:

```
// BoostFileSystem.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "File Size: " << endl;
    cout << file_size("as.jpg");

    return 0;
}
```

It throws error. The error is that:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BoostFileSystem, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  BoostFileSystem.cpp
1>  LINK : C:\...\visual studio 2013\Projects\BoostFileSystem\Debug\BoostFileSystem.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>  BoostFileSystem.vcxproj -> C:\..\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BoostFileSystem\Debug\BoostFileSystem.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

'as.jpg' is also included in the Resources folder. When I remove this line:

```
file_size("as.jpg");
```

The error is not thrown. Also bear in mind that the compiler reports no failure.

What is the problem? I really cannot figure it out.

Because when I remove `file_size()` line, the program works fully and also prints the text on the screen ("File Size:"). While when run it as-is, the compiler throws no error, but no text (even the line before the `file_size()`) is not printer and in the console the following is printed (which is also outputed to the error-area as already pasted above):

UPDATED:

Here is the error shown in the console window:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Ali\do
ts\BoostFileSystem\Debug\BoostFileSystem.exe.
```

Comment: I don't see an error in the output you pasted.

Comment: I'm confused, your compiler says `Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed` but you say there is an error?

Comment: Remember that the default folder in Visual Studio is the one containing the solution file not the resources folder. Also as the others have mentioned you have not shown an error in your question. The bit about performing full link is not an error.

Comment: well with error, I didn't say failure, I said error in doing something. and I explained that "something"

Comment: let me add another to my question, wait please

Comment: I would expect file_size() to throw an exception since the file you as.jpg is in the wrong folder.

Comment: @drescherjm where it should be then?

Comment: In the same folder as the solution file. I said that above.

Comment: I have passed ReadMe.txt in the same place where my BoostFileSystem.sln is, but the same error remains.

Comment: That error message is unusual. Its complaining that it can't find the executable. It should mention the data file not the executable file.

Comment: Although the paths appear to be different. I mean `C:\..\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BoostFileSystem\Debug\BoostFileSystem.exe` versus `C:\Users\Ali\dots\BoostFileSystem\Debug\BoostFileSystem.exe`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I post it for future visitors.

The problem is with incremental linking enabled in MS-Visual Studio C++. If disable it, then the program works.

Go to the properties of the project, then to the Linker, General and Disable the Incremental Linking.

Comment: I think the real problem is your project settings are inconsistent with regards to path meaning the path that the incremental linker believes your executable should be in is different from the actual path. Disabling incremental linking would solve this since it will no longer do that step using the wrong path..